# Installing JMX Agent with WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, jax-rs, wso2-bam

I am trying to monitor some of the MBeans from JMX server in BAM.
I followed http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+Up+JMX+Agent+for+BAM to setup up JMX Agent in BAM. I used WS02 BAM 2.0.1 Version and got the below error.

I am trying to get the correct BAM version supporting the JMX Agent.

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - BAM JMX Agent Aggregate
>   Feature 4.0.5 (org.wso2.carbon.bam.jmx.agent.feature.group 4.0.5)
>   Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge - All
>   Cassandra Features Aggregator Feature 4.0.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.cassandra.feature.group 4.0.2) Only one of
>   the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge -
>   Cassandra Defn Storage Server Feature 4.0.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.jar
>   4.0.2) WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge - Cassandra Defn Storage Server Feature 4.0.5
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.jar
>   4.0.5) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - BAM JMX Agent Aggregate Feature 4.0.5 (org.wso2.carbon.bam.jmx.agent.feature.group
>   4.0.5) To: org.wso2.carbon.bam.jmx.agent.server.feature.group [4.0.5] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - BAM JMX Agent Server
>   Feature 4.0.5 (org.wso2.carbon.bam.jmx.agent.server.feature.group
>   4.0.5) To: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.feature.group
>   [4.0.0,4.1.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Data
>   Bridge - All Cassandra Features Aggregator Feature 4.0.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.cassandra.feature.group 4.0.2) To:
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.group
>   [4.0.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge -
>   Cassandra Defn Storage Aggregator Feature 4.0.5
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.feature.group 4.0.5)
>   To:
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.group
>   [4.0.5] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge -
>   Cassandra Defn Storage Server Feature 4.0.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.group
>   4.0.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.jar
>   [4.0.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge -
>   Cassandra Defn Storage Server Feature 4.0.5
>   (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.group
>   4.0.5) To: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.server.feature.jar
>   [4.0.5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a mistake that this doc related to JMX Agent, is available in BAM 2.0.1. This doc (http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+Up+JMX+Agent+for+BAM) is related to a future up coming version BAM 2.2.0. (http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Setting+Up+JMX+Agent+for+BAM) JMX Agent is not compatible with already released BAM versions.

Comment: Deleted the misleading doc.

Comment: Hi .. Few days back I was able to set JMX Data Agent with pervious version of BAM 2.0.0 and i got the example working !

Comment: You can try with newly released BAM 2.2.0 http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor/ .

Answer (score 0):

Few days back I was able to set JMX Data Agent with pervious version of BAM 2.0.0 and i got the example working